# How much memory does my list use?

Tags: python, numpy, memory, h5py

I'm reading in hdf5 data sets into memory via:

```
import h5py
with h5py.File('file.hdf5') as f:
    a = f['data'][:]
```

where 'a' can have up to 100 million entires.  How can I query exactly how much memory in MB/GB that this list is taking up?

Comment: I don't have hdf5 handy... what type is `a`?

Comment: Add a couple prompts before and after the `with` clause and use normal system tools to check the process memory usage.

Comment: The use of `list` in the title is misleading.  It's an `array`.

Answer (score 1):

`h5py` loads (most) values as `numpy` arrays.  An array has a `shape` attribute, and `dtype`.

For an array that I happen to have in my Ipython session, I can get these attributes:

```
In [211]: X.shape,X.dtype
Out[211]: ((51, 13), dtype('float64'))

In [212]: X.size
Out[212]: 663

In [213]: X.size, X.itemsize
Out[213]: (663, 8)

In [214]: X.nbytes
Out[214]: 5304
```

The Ipython `whos` command also gives me this information:

```
X   ndarray       51x13: 663 elems, type `float64`, 5304 bytes
```

`X` also uses some memory to store attributes like this, but most of the memory use is in the data buffer, which in this case is 5304 bytes long.

`h5py` might have some added information; I'd have to check it's docs. But these are the `numpy` basics.

In the h5py docs I see that a DataSet has shape, size and dtype.  I don't see nbytes or itemsize.  You may have to infer those.

---

For a small sample file, I get (in an Ipython session)

```
In [262]: y
Out[262]: <HDF5 dataset "y": shape (10,), type "<i4">
In [265]: y1=f['y'][:]
```

And the `whos` entries:

```
y             Dataset     <HDF5 dataset "y": shape (10,), type "<i4">
y1            ndarray     10: 10 elems, type `int32`, 40 bytes
```

`y1` is an `ndarray` with all the attributes I described. `y`, unloaded, doesn't have the `nbytes`, but that can be calculated from shape and dtype.